# Never use Cascade Delete becasue we want to keep all logic inside application code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a project and its SQL Server database always use `ON DELETE NO ACTION` regardless, even for Order-OrderItem scenarios.

I recall school professors always ask us to set cascade delete.

Senior developers say it's because we want to keep all logic inside application code, meaning if we want to delete `Order`, our code has to first delete `OrderItem`.

Is it a valid argument? When should `ON DELETE NO ACTION` be used?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's not my preference but handling data integrity at the application or business layer is a known technique.  This needs to be well tested to ensure the application doesn't create orphans.  I've worked with systems where the developers used the business layer to handle foreign key constraints and cascade deletes.  It's very difficult to understand the relationships and behavior if you're working in the backend.  This needs to be well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time these days I see applications that make heavy use of soft delete and it's a different enough concept that a cascading hard delete wrecks it completely, especially if an app tries to mix the two approaches.

Only you can really answer whether your particular project will use cascade delete or not

> Is it a valid argument?

Yes

> When should ON DELETE NO ACTION be used?

When another mechanism is handling relationship maintenance by an alternative means and this mechanism would wreck the effectiveness of that mechanism

Comment: I believe soft delete is to set a flag in database row to mark it as deleted, it's an application concept. When application really needs to delete a database row, I feel if I don't use cascade delete, I end up with writing unnecessary code to delete the referenced rows, where simple DB flag would do the job.

Comment: True, my point is the proliferation of data access layer generators that will get upset if you mix hard delete in with soft delete, and the ORM itself knows the relationships and maintains the cascade of soft deletes. With these systems an application should t ever really "need" to hard delete a row- the storage is cheap compared to the cost of paying a human to sort out an ill performed hard delete, so we keep the data. I'm not sure now what your original question is asking as SO is not for polling opinion, and your question doesn't really have a factual answer